# Source code in C# preprocessor directives and Line numbers from the PDB file

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, preprocessor-directive

One of third party open-source libraries in my project raised a security concern when scanned with Veracode. However, when I checked the source code for the line numbers the issues were raised, they had totally different code without any vulnerability.

Do the line numbers inferred from PDB files include source code present in preprocessor directives even if the symbol is not defined?

Comment: One of C#'s blessings in a preprocessor that cannot change line numbers.   So your guess is not close to accurate.  Tag your question correctly and show the *exact* warnings and source code.

Comment: @HansPassant Does that include even compiler optimization like another comment (now deleted) mentioned?

Comment: @ganeshran it was my deleted comment but it's inaccurate, AFAIK C# compiler won't inline calls, only JIT does then static analysis won't be _cheated_ by that.

Comment: Got it @AdrianoRepetti. !

Comment: @HansPassant Can you post your comment as an answer so I can mark the question as answered?

Comment: Does Vaeracode scan the C# source or the generated assembly? There can be operations that the C# compiler generates in the IDL that may not be obvious in the C# source code.

Comment: [#line (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/34dk387t) - __#line__  lets you modify the compiler's line number and (optionally) the file name output for errors and warnings. This example shows how to report two warnings associated with line numbers. The #line 200 directive forces the line number to be 200 (although the default is #7) and until the next #line directive, the filename will be reported as "Special". The #line default directive returns the line numbering to its default numbering, which counts the lines that were renumbered by the previous directive.

Comment: @PauloMorgado Yeah, but why would anyone use `#line` to point to an unrelated C# file?

Comment: A tool that changes the source code before compiling might do that for debugging info. The point was the it can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of C#'s blessings is a preprocessor that cannot change line numbers.

P.S: This question was answered in the comments